# how to get graphviz records to have cells that line up

Tags: graphviz

I'm using a record node in graphviz to make a simple table, but it looks wrong:

```
   digraph g {
     node [shape = record,height=.08];
     node1[label = "{DBAT|{  0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7}|{8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15}|...|{248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255}}"];
   }
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the subrecords to line up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML-formatted nodes will probably make this easier. See http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html for details. Tables are supported.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it's impossible to do with only record labels, you should try HTML-like syntax.

https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

[image]

[Online Editor](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20g%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node2%5Bshape%3D%22none%22%20label%3D%3C%0A%3CTABLE%20BORDER%3D%220%22%20CELLBORDER%3D%221%22%20CELLSPACING%3D%220%22%20CELLPADDING%3D%226%22%20COLUMNS%3D%22*%22%3E%0A%20%20%3CTR%3E%3CTD%20COLSPAN%3D%228%22%3EDBAT%3C%2FTD%3E%3C%2FTR%3E%0A%20%20%3CTR%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E0%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E1%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E2%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E3%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E4%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E5%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E6%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E7%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FTR%3E%0A%20%20%3CTR%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E8%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E9%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E10%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E11%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E12%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E13%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E14%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E15%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FTR%3E%0A%20%20%3CTR%3E%3CTD%20COLSPAN%3D%228%22%3E...%3C%2FTD%3E%3C%2FTR%3E%0A%20%20%3CTR%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E248%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E249%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E250%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E251%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E252%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E253%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E254%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%3E255%3C%2FTD%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FTR%3E%0A%3C%2FTABLE%3E%3E%5D%3B%0A%7D)

```
digraph g {
    node2[shape="none" label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="6" COLUMNS="*">
  <TR><TD COLSPAN="8">DBAT</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>0</TD>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD>
    <TD>6</TD>
    <TD>7</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>8</TD>
    <TD>9</TD>
    <TD>10</TD>
    <TD>11</TD>
    <TD>12</TD>
    <TD>13</TD>
    <TD>14</TD>
    <TD>15</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR><TD COLSPAN="8">...</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>248</TD>
    <TD>249</TD>
    <TD>250</TD>
    <TD>251</TD>
    <TD>252</TD>
    <TD>253</TD>
    <TD>254</TD>
    <TD>255</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>>];
}
```