# graphviz: HTML nodes have extra box around it?

Tags: graphviz

I'm using [HTML nodes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) for graphviz [per my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067669/how-to-get-graphviz-records-to-have-cells-that-line-up/2067860#2067860). Why do I get the extra box around the outside, and how do I get rid of it? Also how do I make the figure smaller?

```
 digraph g {
     node [shape = record,height=0.08];
     node1[label = <
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
     <TR>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">hello<BR/>world</TD>
        <TD COLSPAN="3">b</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">g</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">h</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>  <TD>c</TD><TD PORT="here">d</TD><TD>e</TD>  </TR>
      <TR>  <TD COLSPAN="3">f</TD>  </TR>
    </TABLE>>];
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

doh! I solved one problem, I was using `node [shape = record`, the `record` is not appropriate if I'm using HTML labels. Changing from "record" to "plaintext" got rid of my extra box and fixed some other problems I was having with named ports.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times more! Thanks for that, I fell into the same trap.

Comment: A second approach is to use *peripheries="0"*, this can be used to offset arrowheads a bit ... but shape="plaintext" is the way to go!