# GraphViz HTML nested tables

Tags: html, html-table, graphviz

I am using GraphViz to make a tabular structure. I was using the `record` style, but the boxes weren't lining up. Given the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067669/how-to-get-graphviz-records-to-have-cells-that-line-up) question, I thought I'd use the HTML style instead. However, I can't seem to properly nest tables. Here's my dot code:

```
digraph test {
    graph [ratio=fill];
    node [label="\N", fontsize=15, shape=plaintext];
    graph [bb="0,0,352,154"];
    arset [label=<
        <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT">
            <TR>
                <TD>Top left</TD>
                <TD>
                    <TABLE>
                        <TR><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Bottom Left</TD>
                <TD>
                    <TABLE>
                        <TR><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    >, ];
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

So many extra lines! Can anyone help me figure out how to properly make a nested table? On the flip side, an answer to the linked question detailing how to get cells to align using the record display would suffice.

Comment: how to remove all spacings that we have subdivision but no spaces ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added BORDER="0" to inner tables

```
digraph test {
    graph [ratio=fill];
    node [label="\N", fontsize=15, shape=plaintext];
    graph [bb="0,0,352,154"];
    arset [label=<
        <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT">
            <TR>
                <TD>Top left</TD>
                <TD>
                    <TABLE BORDER="0">
                        <TR><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Bottom Left</TD>
                <TD>
                    <TABLE BORDER="0">
                        <TR><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    >, ];
}
```

and here is the result

[image]

You can find [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) many other options to control HTML layout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
<TD>
  <TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

You can do this also :

```
<TD COLSPAN="2">Row 1<BR/>Row 2</TD>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Also, do note that this question is about 4 1/2 years old at this point, and a *lot* has changed since then in the world of web development.